# How to fix double back button in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, io, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-navigationstack

I got 2 views. On the second view I have list of exercises and when I choose one of them and go inside I see double back. It's driving me crazy.

First one:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ProgrammView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView{
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack {
                Text("blabla")
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .font(.custom("AvenirNext-Bold", size: 30))
                NavigationLink{
                    InsultHandProgram()
                    
                } label: {
                    Image("35")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .padding(.bottom, 7)
                        .shadow(radius: 5)
                }                  
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Second one:

```
import SwiftUI

struct InsultHandProgram: View {
    let numbers = InsultProgram.getInsultProgram()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(numbers) { InsultProgram in
                NavigationLink( InsultProgram.name, value: InsultProgram)
            }
            .navigationTitle("blabla")
            .navigationDestination(for: InsultProgram.self) {
                InsultProgram in InsultProgrammDetail(InsultProgram: InsultProgram)
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

I tried to change navigation stack. It's crushed.

Comment: You might have used `NavigationView` in one of your previous screen.

Comment: NavigationView (first nav) with NavigationLink pushing a NavigationStack(second nav).

Answer (score 0):

If you use `NavigationView`, then it provides the navigation bars for all its child views. `NavigationStack` in your child view **also** wants to provide a navigation bar, and so you end up with two.

To remedy the situation you have some choices:

1. Remove the `NavigationStack` from your child view and let `NavigationView` manage everything.
2. Remove `NavigationStack` from you child view and replace `NavigationView` in your parent with a `NavigationStack`. This will work fine on iPhones, but doesn't adapt well to iPads.
3. Keep your navigation stack in the child view but replace `NavigationView` with `NavigationSplitView`. This came in with iOS16, as did `NavigationStack`. The two work well together so they don't step on each other's toes when it comes to setting up navigation bars.

Given you're already using other iOS 16 idioms such as `navigationDestination` I'd recommend approach 3.